Testing for Homoscedasticity - should Levene's and Brown-Forsythe use Welch's t-test/ANOVA?
This question just came up and I haven't seen any literature on the subject.
Background: When testing homoscedasticity for, say, a two-sample t-test, the F-test for equal variances is deprecated due to its high sensitivity to non-normal distributions. Levene's test (a t-test or equivalently an F-test on the absolute deviation of observations from the group averages - ADA) is recommended for its robustness. Further robustness can be attained using Brown-Forsythe's modification using the absolute deviation from the medians (ADM).
However, if there is indeed a difference in the dispersion between two groups, I think we would expect that the variances of the ADAs or ADMs would also be different. The classical Student's t is not great at handling differences in variances, and this is made worse if the sample sizes are not equal. When testing means, I recommend univerally using Welch's t-test for this reason.
Question: Using the same reasoning, where we expect differences in variances when group dispersions are different, should Levene's and Brown-Forsythe's tests for dispersion also use Welch's t-test (or Welch's ANOVA for more than two groups) instead of the classical Student's t or F?

Hi @COOLSerdash, yep, I know that. I thought I had explicitly said that above. I advise always using Welch for testing for differences in the means. My question is related to testing for differences in dispersion when using Levene / Brown-Forsythe. When performing these tests (which use the t or F) would it not instead be better to use Welch when testing for dispersion? Thanks!

Could you clarify when you would think using a Levene test would be needed? Hence your question about making it about as correct as possible. Certainly  not for t (as you mention), or ANOVA, which both have a Welch flavor. What other situation do you have in mind where homoscedasticity is a needed assumption, to be "verified" by Levene?

Thanks @jginestet. It is not to test for an assumption, but rather to detect if the variance / dispersion has changed due to the treatment.
